# PowerShell #requires and .SYNOPSIS don't play nice

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

You can tag your PowerShell script as [requiring a particular version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/02/06/requires-your-scripts.aspx):

```
#requires -version 2.0
```

You can put extra help text in your PowerShell script:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Frobnicates the blargnozzle.
#>
```

Unfortunately, they don't appear to play nice:

- If you put the `#requires` on line 1, `Get-Help Frob-Blargnozzle.ps1` doesn't display the synopsis, only the parameter summary.
- If you put the `#requires` on any line other than line one, even if immediately after the `<# ... #>` comment, it is ignored.

Suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea, but *“Frobnicates the blargnozzle.”* is such a wonderful documentation that it deserves an upvote ;-)

Comment: Hmmm. I appear to be a bit mixed up: the `#requires` can go on any line in the script... I'll investigate why I was seeing problems before.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put `#requires -version 2.0`  one line up the closing comment `#>`

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Frobnicates the blargnozzle.

#requires -version 2.0
#>
```

Comment: That seems to cause the #requires text to become part of the documentation

Comment: @DavidGardiner Good. Seems like something that should be included in documentation don't you think?

Comment: Well yes, but in doing that is it still performing the function of enforcing a minimum version?

Answer (score 3):

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Requires) is, on first inspection, a bit confusing:

> **RULES FOR USE**
>
> - The #Requires statement must be the first item on a line in a script.
> - A script can include more than one #Requires statement.
> - The #Requires statements can appear on any line in a script.

This is easily misinterpreted as saying that you need to put the `#Requires` on the first line. In fact, what it is saying is that you can put a `#Requires` on *any* lines, but it needs to be the *only* thing on those lines.

Also, you *can* put `#Requires` on the first line, and still have a working `.SYNOPSIS` - you just need to include a blank line in-between:

```
#Requires -Version 3

<#
.SYNOPSIS
My script
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the #Requires outside of a comment block (<#..#>).  It can be on any line of the script but I tend to put them after the initial comment block before any other blocks or code.